# Do I need momentJS if I'm using moment-with-locales?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

Right now I'm adding scripts in my project in following sequence:

```
window.top.ak.getScript([
    window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/css/xxx.css",
    window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/xxx.min.js",
    window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/polyfills.min.js",
    window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/jquery.min.js",
    currHost + "/components/lib/lodash.min.js",
    window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/moment.min.js",
    window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/angular.min.js"
], function() {
    window.top.ak.getScript([
        window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/angular-messages.js",
        window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/angular-ui-router.js",
        window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/angular-animate.js",
        currHost + "/components/lib/toaster.min.js",
        window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/ui-grid.min.js",
        currHost + "/components/lib/defiant.min.js",
        window.top.akContextPath + "/scripts/js/xxx-ui.js",
        currHost + "/components/lib/polyfill-resize.js",
        currHost + "/components/lib/draggable-rows.js",
        currHost + "/components/lib/moment-with-locales.js",
    ], function() {
        window.top.ak.getAsset([
            currHost + "/components/common.bundle.js",
            currHost + "/components/myApp." + pagePath + ".bundle.js"
        ], document);
    }, document);
}, document);
```

Where `getScript`/`getAsset` methods are adding these files to HTML. Which works quite fine.

But after inspection I'm curious do I need `moment.min.js`, if I'm using `moment-with-locales.js`, am I right?

If it is, where I can put it. is there any library other then `xxx.**.js` uses it?

Comment: You don't need moment.min.js if you already use moment-with-locales.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moment-with-locales.js is moment, with locales added ;-). So you don't need moment-min.js. Looking through the list of scripts, the other ones don't seem to need momentjs. But then again, momentjs is as basic as jQuery, so why not put it right in the top?